# The current security context cannot be reverted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, logins, dmv

> Msg 15199, Level 16, State 1, Line 29 T he current security context
>   cannot be reverted.
>
> Please switch to the original database where `Execute As` was called
>   and try it again.

```
execute as login='juno'
REVERT


DECLARE @User VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @USER = SUBSTRING(SUSER_SNAME(), CHARINDEX('\', SUSER_SNAME()) + 1, LEN(SUSER_SNAME()))
SELECT  [THE_SERVER]= @@SERVERNAME
        ,[DB_NAME] =DB_NAME()
        ,[@USER]=@USER 
        ,[SUSER_SNAME()]=SUSER_SNAME()
        ,[SYSTEM_USER]=SYSTEM_USER
        ,[USER_NAME()]=USER_NAME() 
        ,[CURRENT_USER]=CURRENT_USER
        ,[ORIGINAL_LOGIN()]=ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
        ,[USER]=USER
        ,[SESSION_USER]=SESSION_USER
```

[image]

What if I can't remember the original database I was when I executed the `execute as login`?

Is there a way to find out where I was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find it out, but you can try all the databases accessible by that login, i.e. under impersonated login execute the following code:

```
select 'use ' + name + '; revert;'
from sys.databases
where HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;
```

This way you find all the databases from which you could impersonate this login. Then you copy the output to query window and try it row by row until success.

But the easiest way to return yourself is just to change connection (right click in query window)

[image]

Comment: Note that query only works if the impersonated identity has `view any database` permission.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Any newly created login BY DEFAULT has VIEW ANY DATABASE permission as inherited from public fixed server role. If for any reason someone revoke/deny this DEFAULT permission he should write about it, shouldn't he?